# Балансировка бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

Нужно написать балансировку бинарного дерева поиска. Есть понимание что такое балансировка, но как перевести его в код я не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начать?

```
struct Elem
{
    char eng[15]; // ключ
    char rus[15]; // значение
    Elem *left/*левый потомок*/, *right/*правый потомок*/, *parent/*родитель*/;
};

class Tree
{
    // корень
    Elem * root;
    // количество узлов
    int count;
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    // печать от указанного узла
    void Print(Elem * Node);
    // поиск от указанного узла
    Elem * Search(Elem * Node, char * key);
    // min от указанного узла
    Elem * Min(Elem * Node);
    // max от указанного узла
    Elem * Max(Elem * Node);
    // следующий для указанного узла
    Elem * Next(Elem * Node);
    // предыдущий для указанного узла
    Elem * Previous(Elem * Node);
    // вставка узла
    void Insert(Elem * z);
    // удаление ветки для указанного узла, 
    void Del(Elem * z);
    // количество узлов дерева
    int GetCount(){ return count; }
    // получить корень
    Elem * GetRoot();
    void Save(Elem *node, FILE *f1);
    void Balanse();
};
```

Comment: Найдите где-нибудь готовую реализации и переделайте под себя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Балансировкой называют приведение дерева к высоте log(2,n), где n число элементов. Это ускоряет операции с ним.

Для начала надо определиться с тем когда собственно проводить баллансировку. Есть 2 варианта:

1. Во время каждой вставки.
2. Периодически по мере разрастания дерева.

Второй вариант кажется мне более выгодным. Так как удаления и вставки в таком случае можно производить просто грубым методом.

Саму балансировку стоит производить [алгоритмом DSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm) со сложностью O(n)(и O(1) пространственной). [Оригинальная статья](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~qstout/pap/CACM86.pdf) и [еще одна](http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/DSWpaper/)

В кратце он [вращениями](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation) конвертирует несбаллансированное дерево в вырожденный связный список "лиану" и далее из "лианы" с помощью вращений возвращает уже сбаллансированное дерево.